# How to mix different symbols for legend keys in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code that produces the figure.

```
cols <- brewer.pal(n = 3, name = 'Dark2')

p4 <- ggplot(all.m, aes(x=xval, y=yval, colour = Approach, ymax = 0.95)) + theme_bw() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= yval - se, ymax = yval + se), width=5, position=pd) + 
  geom_line(position=pd) + geom_point(position=pd) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = cp.best$slope, colour = "C2P"), show_guide = FALSE) + 
  scale_color_manual(name="Appraoch", breaks=c("C2P", "P2P", "CP2P"), values =  cols[c(1,3,2)]) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.4, 0.95, 0.05), "Test AUROC") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 150, by = 20), "# Number of Patient Samples in Training")

p4 <- p4 + theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
      legend.position = 'top', 
      plot.margin = unit(c(5.1, 7, 4.5, 3.5)/2, "lines"), 
      text = element_text(size=15), axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=-1.5), axis.title.y=element_text(vjust=2))   
p4
```

[image: Figure Produced]

How can I change the symbol to a line without a dot in the legend for "C2P" only, without affecting the symbols for "P2P" and "CP2P"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the point marker from the legend using `override.aes` by adding the following line of code to your plot:

```
guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=c(NA,16,16))))
```

`override.aes` changes the legend without changing the plot. In this case, we want to change the legend point markers, so we want to change the `shape` of the points. Point marker number 16 is a filled circle (see `?pch`), which we want to keep for two of the markers, but we use `NA` to remove the point marker for the first item in the legend.

Comment: Another way is to use `show_guide = FALSE` in `geom_point()`.

Comment: That will remove the point markers from all of the legend values, rather than removing the point marker for just `C2P`.

Comment: @eipi10 what if I want the shape of the plot to also have different shapes which correspond to the legend

Comment: Then add a shape aesthetic inside aes, just like you would for colour or fill. If you want to choose your own point shapes, also add a scale_shape_manual statement.